# Table caption centering

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, captions

I'm trying to center the caption of my table, but it seems i'm not getting it right. I'm working with a header file (thesis.tex) where I declare al the packages I used and input different chapters. The table is code from a chapter.

I'm getting this:

[image]

Code:

```
\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \caption{Infrarood spectrum}
    \begin{tabular}{| c | c |}
        \hline
        Naam & Golflengte \\
        \hline
        Near Infrared (NIR) & 700 nm - 1.5 $\mu$m \\
        Short Wavelength Infrared (SWIR) & 1.5 $\mu$m - 3 $\mu$m \\
        Mid Wavelength Infrared (MWIR) & 3 $\mu$m - 8 $\mu$m\\
        Long Wanelength Infrared (LWIR) & 8 $\mu$m - 15 $\mu$m \\
        Far Infrared (FIR) & 15 $\mu$m - 1 mm \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \label{tab:infraroodSpectrum}
\end{table}
```

Thesis.tex:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%                                                                      %
% LaTeX, FIIW thesis template                                          %
%                                                                      %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
% Indien je je thesis recto-verso wil afdrukken gebruik je onderstaande opties i.p.v. bovenstaande
%\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{report}

\usepackage[a4paper,left=3.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=3.5cm, bottom=3.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}           % om niet ascii karakters rechtstreeks te kunnen inputten
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}            % commentarieer deze regel uit als je utf8 encoded files gebruikt in plaats van latin1
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{listings}                   % voor het weergeven van broncode
\usepackage{verbatim}                   % weergeven van code, commando's, ...
\usepackage{hyperref}                   % maak PDF van de thesis navigeerbaar
\usepackage{url}                        % URL's invoegen in tekst met behulp van \url{http://}
\usepackage[small,bf,hang]{caption}     % om de captions wat te verbeteren
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}            % gebruikt voor het invoegen van het artikel in pdf-formaat
\usepackage{pslatex}                    % andere lettertype's dan de standaard types
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{sectsty}                    % aanpassen van de fonts van sections en chapters
%\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}  % Bibliography mee in de ToC

\allsectionsfont{\sffamily}
\chapterfont{\raggedleft\sffamily}

\usepackage{float}                      % De optie H voor de plaatsing van figuren op de plaats waar je ze invoegt. bvb. \begin{figure}[H]
%\usepackage{longtable}                 % tabellen die over meerdere pagina's gespreid worden
%\usepackage[times]{quotchap}           % indien je fancy hoofdstuktitels wil
%\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
%\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}           %footnote onderaan pagina, niet meer aan tekst "gelijmd"
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[]{algorithm2e}

% MFA: zet zoekpad voor figure
\graphicspath{{afbeeldingen/}}

\usepackage{fiiw}
% \usepackage{fiiw_denayer_eng} % For the english version (also change last page at the bottom of this file!

%door onderstaande regels in commentaar te zetten, of op false, kan je pagina's weglaten
%bijvoorbeeld het weglaten van een voorwoord, lijst met symbolen, ...
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%voorwoord toevoegen?
\acknowledgementspagetrue
\acknowledgements{voorwoord}            %.tex file met daarin het voorwoord

%samenvatting toevoegen
%\summarypagetrue
%\summary{samenvatting}                 %.tex met daarin de samenvatting

%abstract toevoegen?
\abstractpagetrue
\abstracts{abstract}                    %.tex file met daarin het abstract
%lijst van figuren toevoegen?
\listoffigurespagetrue
%lijst van tabellen toevoegen?
\listoftablespagetrue
%lijst van symbolen toevoegen?
\listofsymbolspagetrue
\listofsymbols{symbolen}                %.tex file met daarin de lijst van symbolen
%lijst van afkortingen toevoegen?
\listofabbrevspagetrue
\listofabbrevs{afkortingen}             %.tex file met daarin de lijst van symbolen

%informatie over het eindwerk, de promotor, ...
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\opleiding{Elektronica-ICT ICT}
\afdeling{ }

\campus{denayer} %denayer,denayereng,geel,geeleng,gent,ghenteng,groept,groupteng,brugge,brugeseng

\title{Detectie van landingsplatformen voor drones}
\subtitle{}
% \author{naam student}
\forenameA{Simon}
\surnameA{Vleugels}

% l
\forenameB{}
\surnameB{}

\academicyear{2017 - 2018}

\promotorA[Promotor]{Prof. dr. ir. Toon Goedemé }
\promotorB[Co-promotor]{Ing. Maarten Vandersteegen}
\promotorC[]{}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{dutch}
% \selectlanguage{english} % For the english version
\preface

\input{hfdst1-SitueringEnDoelstelling}
\input{hfdst2-Literatuurstudie}
\input{hfdst3-Landingsplatformen}
\input{hfdst4-Behuizing}
\input{hfdst5-communicatieRPI-PX}
\input{hfdst6-ROS-framework}
\input{hfdst7-Testen}
\input{hfdst8-Resultaten}
\input{hfdst9-Besluit}
% Bibliografie: referenties. De items zitten in bibliografie.bib
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Indien je ook de niet geciteerde werken in je bibliografie wil opnemen, commentarieer dan onderstaande regel uit!
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{bibliografie}

% Eventueel enkele appendices
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\appendix
\input{bijlageA}

% Back cover: change according to the correct campus
\includepdf{private/back_fiiw_denayer.pdf}
% \includepdf{private/back_fiiw_denayer_eng.pdf} % For the english version
%\includepdf{private/back_fiiw_geel.pdf}
% \includepdf{private/back_fiiw_geel_eng.pdf} % For the english version
%\includepdf{private/back_fiiw_gent.pdf}
% \includepdf{private/back_fiiw_ghent_eng.pdf} % For the english version
%\includepdf{private/back_fiiw_brugge.pdf}
% \includepdf{private/back_fiiw_bruges_eng.pdf} % For the english version
%\includepdf{private/back_fiiw_groept.pdf}
% \includepdf{private/back_fiiw_groupt_eng.pdf} % For the english version

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. In particular the answer highly depends on the class and packages used (KOMA-script based answers would differ a lot from package `caption` for example).

Comment: B.t.w. don't use the `center` environment with `figure` or `table`. It just adds unwanted vertical spacing. `\centering` does the job.

Comment: I edited my question. I hope this can help you/me

Comment: Could you please clarify from where you got `fiiw.sty` as it is not available at [CTAN](https://ctan.org/) but seems to be responsible for the caption design. Maybe it already helps to add `\captionsetup[table]{justification=centering}` to your preamble.

Comment: The fiiw is a package made by the faculty of my university. \captionsetup[table]{justification=centering} isn't doing anything

Comment: Without seeing the actual code of `fiiw.sty` this is still just a guess, but try putting the `\captionsetup` command after `\usepackage{fiiw}`

Comment: Alright placing the \captionsetup (what is the key shortcut for code?) after the \usepackage helped!

Comment: To begin/end in line code you can use the 'grave accent symbol'. For more formatting possibilities in comments, you can click on the `help` link just beneath the `add comment` button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fiiw` package seems to use the `\captionsetup` command from the `caption` package to left align table captions.
To instead print them horizontally centered, you can add `\captionsetup[table]{justification=centering}` after `\usepackage{fiiw}`.